# posix threads and O3 optimisations

Tags: c++, optimization, pthreads

I am working on a program that uses mpi (openmpi 1.4.3) and pthreads, working in c++ under linux.

some of the mpi nodes have a queuing system implemented with pthreads.
Idea is simple one thread adding elements into queue, and few other "working" threads picking up objects and doing their job on them (not a rocket science).

Please consider 2 examples of my working threads which picking up elements. 
First example working fine unless -O3 optimization is specified. In that case it starts to endlessly looping without picking up anything.

```
    while (true){
        if (t_exitSignal[tID]){
            dorun = false;
            break;
        }

        //cout<<"w8\n";

        //check if queue has some work for us
        if (!frame_queue->empty()){

            //try to get lock and recheck that queue no empty
            pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex_frame_queue );

            if (!frame_queue->empty()){
                cout<<"Pickup "<<tID<<endl;
                con = frame_queue->front();
                frame_queue->pop();
                t_idling[tID] = false;
                pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_frame_queue );
                break;
            }

            pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_frame_queue );
        }

    }
```

Now consider this one, exactly the same code, except mutex gettimg locked before I checking for queue->empthy. This work works fine for all levels of optimization.

```
    while (true){
        if (t_exitSignal[tID]){
            dorun = false;
            break;
        }
        //cout<<"w8\n";

        //try to get lock and recheck that queue no empty
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex_frame_queue );

        //check if queue has some work for us
        if (!frame_queue->empty()){

                cout<<"Pickup "<<tID<<endl;
                con = frame_queue->front();
                frame_queue->pop();
                t_idling[tID] = false;
                pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_frame_queue );
                break;

        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_frame_queue );

    }
```

Just in case it make a difference this is how I populate queue from other thread

```
                    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex_frame_queue );
            //adding the same contianer into queue to make it available for threads
            frame_queue->push(*cursor);
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_frame_queue );
```

My question is: why first example of code stop working why I compiling with -O3 option ?
Any other suggestion for the queuing system ?

Thanks a lot!

SOLUTION: This is what I come up with at the end. Seems to work much better than either of the methods above. (just in case someone interested ;)

```
    while (true){

        if (t_exitSignal[tID]){

            dorun = false;
            break;
        }
        //try to get lock and check that queue no empty
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex_frame_queue );

        if (!frame_queue->empty()){

            con = frame_queue->front();
            frame_queue->pop();
            t_idling[tID] = false;
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_frame_queue );
            break;
        }else{

            pthread_cond_wait(&conf_frame_queue, &mutex_frame_queue);
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_frame_queue );
        }




    }
```

Adding

```
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex_frame_queue );

        //adding the same contianer into queue to make it available for threads
        frame_queue->push(*cursor);
        //wake up any waiting threads
        pthread_cond_signal(&conf_frame_queue);
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_frame_queue )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are seeing a bug based on assumptions about instruction ordering when you check if the queue is empty - when you turn up the optimization the ordering changes and it breaks because the mutex you have hasn't put up a memory barrier protecting this from occurring.

Answer (score 2):

I'm tempted to suggest `__sync_synchronize()` before the first empty check, but that's probably not safe—if another thread's in the middle of adding to the container, that container may still be in an inconsistent state when you call `empty()`. Depending on the container, anything could happen, from getting back the wrong answer to crashing.

[Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866861/posix-threads-and-o3-optimisations/6866903#6866903) is probably right too. Locking a mutex also provides a memory barrier, which among other things means your code will re-read the memory it's using to determine whether the container's empty each time. Without some sort of memory barrier, that's never actually guaranteed to happen, so at higher optimization levels your code may never see the change.

Also, have you looked into pthread's [condition variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html)? They would allow you to avoid polling in a loop until your container's no longer empty.